# AWS: Custom EC2 instance with an amount of RAM, which deviates from the official AWS EC2 instance offers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need an EC2 instance with 4 CPUs and 2, at most 4 GB of RAM, which is not offered by AWS. So my question is: Is it somehow possible to create your own custom instance-type with CPU and RAM as per your requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to create custom instance types in AWS. I think Google offers that. You need to work out which instance type works best for you and go with that.

The t3 series might be over-specified in some ways, and have a lot more RAM than you need, but are also cheap because you get fractional CPU. C series, compute optimised, tend to have the most cores for a given amount of RAM.

Couple instance options

- t3.xlarge, 4 cores 16GB RAM, $0.1664 / hr
- c5.xlarge, 4 cores 8GB RAM, $0.17 / hr

The c5 gives you constant CPU, t3 gives you burst CPU. The C5 looks like a better option here. Not sure why the t series is almost as expensive given you only get fractional CPU - not sure the fraction as I haven't looked it up.

Curious what your workload is, and why you need four cores? A specific app, or just a busy server? It's not a large core count, but you can get a lot done with one, two, or four modern cores.